# publish power bi to local share point server

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, powerbi

Is it possible that I can publish my Power BI dashboard into local sharepoint server?

Find the solution for office 365: [here](https://ppm4all.com/2016/02/04/publish-power-bi-report-to-sharepoint-online/)

But i need to have my dashboard on local sharepoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, 
because for this feature you are using the public preview feature (mind the preview, it will not remain free). 
This generates an iframe with a connection to powerbi.com in it, so can be published on any html website.